# White space when printing full page world map plot

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying get a full page plot of a world map on a A4 landscape PDF. When I use the following

```
pdf("temp.pdf", paper="a4r")
#par(mar=rep(0,4))
map("world", mar = rep(0,4))
dev.off()
```

I get

[image]

I can not seem to get the plot to fill the page. Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
pdf("temp.pdf", paper="a4r",width=0,height=0)
map("world")
dev.off()
```

which looks odd but works, and is mentioned in the docs. It gives me a world map that fills the page left-right, but not top-bottom because it is keeping the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract coordinates:

```
coord <- map.poly(database="world", regions=".", exact=FALSE,
        xlim=NULL, ylim=NULL, boundary=TRUE, interior=TRUE, fill=FALSE,
        as.polygon=TRUE)
```

and then plot whatever you want with `coord$x` and `coord$y`.